# Break Data Divided by Comma

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a crawler using arduino, a gps module and a gsm.

I can receive the latitude, longitude and send to the cell phone as SMS, but on the cell phone I am trying to build a react-native application, in which I am learning, that shows the location on the map.

Running tests, I got this code to monitor incoming messages:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

import SmsListener from 'react-native-android-sms-listener';

export default class App extends Component {

  //constructor include last message
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { lastMessage: 1 };
  }

  sms(){
    SmsListener.addListener(message => {
      this.setState({ lastMessage: message.body });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> Scheduled jobs: {this.state.lastMessage} </Text>

        <Button 
          title="Buscar" 
          color="#115E54" 
          onPress={() => this.sms() } 
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And this code to display the map:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    latitude: 0.0000,
    longitude: 0.0000,
  };

  render() {
    const { region } = this.props;
    const { latitude, longitude } = this.state;
    console.log(region);

    return (
      <View style ={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          initialRegion={{
            latitude,
            longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0042,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0031,
          }}
          style={styles.map}
          rotateEnabled={false}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          //zoomEnabled={false}
          showsPointsOfInterest={false}
          showBuildings={false}
        >
          <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={{
              latitude: 0.0000,
              longitude: 0.0000,
            }}
          />
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});
```

Both function within their functions.

The problem is in the fact that I get the data in SMS format `0.0000, 0.0000` and I need to break this data in two to be able to allocate in `latitude` and `longitude`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.split()` to separate the data into an array.

```
const [latitude, longitude] = coordData.split(', ')
```

where `coordData = <coordinate string>`.

Javascript Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like:

```
const [latitude, longitude] = "0.0000, 0.0000".split(', ');
```